# TextInput Doesn't Get Focus Inside a Modal - React Native Android

Tags: android, react-native

I have 4 TextInputs in a Modal, the first TextInput get the focus without any problem, but the rest don't get focus. To be more accurate when you click it seems that they get the focus and loose as soon as they get it.

```
 <Modal
   animationType={"fade"}
   transparent={false}
   visible={modalVisible}
   onRequestClose={() => {alert("Modal has been closed.")}}
   >
  <View style={{paddingTop: 22, height: Dimensions.get('window').height , backgroundColor: 'rgba(252,84,102,0.9)'}}>
   <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
     <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'flex-start', alignItems: 'center'}}>
       <View style={{flex: 0.2, flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'flex-start', justifyContent: 'flex-start'}}>
         <TouchableHighlight underlayColor={'rgba(0,0,0,0)'} style={{flex: 0.2, left: 20, alignItems: 'flex-start', justifyContent: 'flex-start'}} onPress={() => {
           setModalVisible(!modalVisible)
         }}>
           <Text style={{textAlign: 'center', color: 'white', fontSize: 35}}>X</Text>
         </TouchableHighlight>
         <View style={{flex: 0.8}}></View>
       </View>
       <View style={{flex: 0.6, width: Dimensions.get('window').width, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', bottom: 100}}>
         <View style={{height: 180, width: 280, backgroundColor: '#5CA4F9', elevation: 5, borderRadius: 5}}>
           <View style={{flex: 0.25}}>
             <Text style={{marginVertical: 5, marginHorizontal: 10, color: 'white', fontFamily: helpers.getFont(), fontSize: 18}}>
               Credit Card
             </Text>
           </View>
           <View style={{flex: 0.25, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', marginVertical: 5}}>
             <TextInput style={{flex: 1, width: 260, backgroundColor: 'white', borderRadius: 5}} placeholder="Card Name Holder"/>
           </View>
           <View style={{flex: 0.25, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', marginVertical: 5}}>
             <TextInput style={{flex: 1, width: 260, backgroundColor: 'white', borderRadius: 5}} placeholder="Card Number"/>
           </View>
           <View style={{flex: 0.25, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', marginVertical: 10}}>
             <View style={{flex: 0.5, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', marginHorizontal: 5}}>
               <TextInput style={{flex:1, width: 120, backgroundColor: 'white', borderRadius: 5}} placeholder="Expires (12/20)"/>
             </View>
             <View style={{flex: 0.5, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', marginHorizontal: 5}}>
               <TextInput style={{flex:1, width: 120, backgroundColor: 'white', borderRadius: 5}} placeholder="CSV Number"/>
             </View>
           </View>
         </View>
         <View style={{height: Dimensions.get('window').height * 0.35, width: Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.9, backgroundColor: 'white', bottom: 100,  borderRadius: 5, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
           <View style={{flex: 0.5}}>
           </View>
           <Text style={{flex: 0.1, fontFamily: helpers.getFont(), fontSize: 16, fontWeight: '500'}}>
             Enter your card information above.
           </Text>
           <View style={{flex: 0.1}}></View>
           <TouchableHighlight style={{flex: 0.2, height: 10, width: Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.70, backgroundColor: 'rgba(84,191,175,1)', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', borderRadius: 3}}>
             <Text style={{fontFamily: helpers.getFont(), color: 'white', fontSize: 18, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
               Add Card
             </Text>
           </TouchableHighlight>
           <View style={{flex: 0.1}}></View>
         </View>
       </View>
     </View>
   </View>
  </View>
 </Modal>
```

I am also attaching a gif to further illustrate the problem I am facing

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution to this, the reason behind the problem I was facing it's because two views were overlapping siblings views were and they interfered with each other. What I had to do to solve this problem is swap the places of the two siblings. Here is my solution:

```
   <View style={{height: Dimensions.get('window').height * 0.35, width: Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.9, backgroundColor: 'white', top: 100,  borderRadius: 5, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
         <View style={{flex: 0.5}}>
         </View>
         <Text style={{flex: 0.1, fontFamily: helpers.getFont(), fontSize: 16, fontWeight: '500'}}>
           Enter your card information above.
         </Text>
         <View style={{flex: 0.1}}></View>
         <TouchableHighlight style={{flex: 0.2, height: 10, width: Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.70, backgroundColor: 'rgba(84,191,175,1)', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', borderRadius: 3}}>
           <Text style={{fontFamily: helpers.getFont(), color: 'white', fontSize: 18, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
             Add Card
           </Text>
         </TouchableHighlight>
         <View style={{flex: 0.1}}></View>
       </View>
       <View style={{flex: 0.6, width: Dimensions.get('window').width, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', bottom: 260}}>
         <View style={{height: 180, width: 280, backgroundColor: '#5CA4F9', elevation: 5, borderRadius: 5}}>
           <View style={{flex: 0.25}}>
             <Text style={{marginVertical: 5, marginHorizontal: 10, color: 'white', fontFamily: helpers.getFont(), fontSize: 18}}>
               Credit Card
             </Text>
           </View>
           <View style={{flex: 0.25, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', marginVertical: 5}}>
             <TextInput style={{flex: 1, width: 260, backgroundColor: 'white', borderRadius: 5}} placeholder="Card Name Holder"/>
           </View>
           <View style={{flex: 0.25, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', marginVertical: 5}}>
             <TextInput style={{flex: 1, width: 260, backgroundColor: 'white', borderRadius: 5}} placeholder="Card Number"/>
           </View>
           <View style={{flex: 0.25, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', marginVertical: 10}}>
             <View style={{flex: 0.5, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', marginHorizontal: 5}}>
               <TextInput style={{flex:1, width: 120, backgroundColor: 'white', borderRadius: 5}} placeholder="Expires (12/20)"/>
             </View>
             <View style={{flex: 0.5, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', marginHorizontal: 5}}>
               <TextInput style={{flex:1, width: 120, backgroundColor: 'white', borderRadius: 5}} placeholder="CSV Number"/>
             </View>
           </View>
         </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import Modal from 'react-native-modal';
```

avoidKeyboard={true} using this keyboard autofocus on text field

```
<Modal
    visible={isVisible}
    onRequestClose={onCheckedInActionClick}
    avoidKeyboard={true}>

  <View> </View>
```